# Hibernate EntityManager not managed by wildfly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying to add hibernate to old project that is currently using plain SQLs + `SeesionContext`/`DataSource` classes. My problem is that I can't force Wildfly (version 21) to manage `EntityManager`. `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("customJpa").createEntityManager();` is working correctly, persistence.xml file is read correctly.
I've tried to inject `@PersistenceUnit` for EntityManagerFactory, add hibernate annotations repo etc. but without any success. I'm basically stuck after trying every possible solution I've found in documentation or here.
I'm probably doing some silly mistake, but I can't figure that out.

`persistence.xml` file is located under `src\main\resources\META-INF\persistence.xml`, in WAR - `deployments\project.war\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\persistence.xml`.

build.gradle:

```
implementation([
...
'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.3.Final',
'com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8:19.3.0.0'
])
```

Persistence.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">
    <persistence-unit name="customJpa" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/customDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.entities.Entity</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl"/>
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.worker.backend" value="jms"/>
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.worker.jms.connection_factory" value="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>
            <!-- Uncomment only for debugging -->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

DB settings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
    <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/customDS" pool-name="pollXADS">
        <xa-datasource-class>...</xa-datasource-class>
        <xa-datasource-property name="URL">...</xa-datasource-property>
        <driver>ojdbc7.jar</driver>
        <security>
            <user-name>...</user-name>
            <password>...</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
            <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
            <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
        </validation>
        <xa-pool>
            <min-pool-size>0</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
            <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
        </xa-pool>
        <timeout>
            <blocking-timeout-millis>10000</blocking-timeout-millis>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>10</idle-timeout-minutes>
        </timeout>
    </xa-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Java base repo class:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public abstract class BaseRepositoryImpl<Entity, Id> implements BaseRepository<Entity, Id>
{
    private final Class<Entity> clazz;
    
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "customJpa")
    private final EntityManager em;
    
    protected BaseRepositoryDAO(Class<Entity> clazz)
    {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.em = getEntityManager();
    }
    
    ...
    
    //Workaroud - creating entityManager using Persistence class is working
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager()
    {
        if (em != null)
        {
            return em;
        }
        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("customJpa").createEntityManager();
    }
```

Comment: Your getEntityManager is the problem, and that it is being called in the constructor. Remove your workaround and try again, as it is going to call Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("customJpa") every time - importantly, the first time, which will force the Persistence static factory loading.

Comment: Removing that didn't solve the problem - EntityManager is always null after removing that workaround. I also tried to inject EntityManager in classes that extends this abstract `BaseRepositoryImpl` class, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Cut and paste error - you show BaseRepositoryImpl with a BaseRepositoryDAO constructor. Do you have any injection working in your app? if not, step back and see why - how are you getting your repository instances, and what does the container log when it builds it?

Comment: you specify a class but exclude-unlisted-classes is set to false